# Automatic location in textfield Google map

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I'm trying  to get the location inside the text field automatically when ever I write some location! but it's not working and no location is showing up when I write something.

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
       <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places">
      type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};            
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); }         
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
     </head>
      <body>
      <label for="searchTextField">Please insert an address:</label>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried your code there is a problem with one of your closing `</script>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- You forgot closing this -->
       <!-- You forgot starting the below script tag -->
       <script>
       function initialize() {
         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};            
         new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
       }         
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <label for="searchTextField">Please insert an address:</label>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get user's current location (Country & City) there are multiple ways pf doing that. You can get that by using the visitors IP address:

```
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$addr = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip='.$ip);
$addr = json_decode($addr, TRUE);
$countryAndCity = $addr["country_name"].", ".$addr["city"];
echo $countryAndCity;
```

Note that this might not be accurate and can be falsified.

Comment: @bilal Yes, just copy paste this code and check, it is working fine for me.

Comment: @bilal do you want to display user's current location first in the text field ? and then the user will use the auto complete in that text field?

Comment: yes exactly the same!! and the map only giving location on United states

Comment: i want to show user current location! and then he can change it! and the map only showing united states

Comment: can u answer quick pls :D the current location! thanks man i appriciate alot!

Comment: @bilal Check my updated answer, you can pass `$countryAndCity` as your textfields value.

Comment: okay map is showing malaysia now as i want but in current location private  address showing up

Comment: @bilal If you're running the code on your local machine then private address will show.

Comment: oh okay! got it thank you so much man! @criesto one more thing can you tell me how to do a cookie to remember the user name when ever we log in!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

JS

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

HTML

```
<label for="searchTextField">Please Insert an address:</label>
<br>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
```

Here is the fiddle example which works: http://jsfiddle.net/moinsam/SDPHm/light/
My suggestion is to separate JS from HTML.